# Redireccionar todas las url a una url especifica htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

tengo un sistema en una carpeta

```
midominio.com/cliente
```

y cuando estoy en "modo mantenimiento" quisiera suspender cualquier acceso al sistema mediante htaccess, es decir si ingreso `midominio.com/cliente/hola.php` o `midominio.com/cliente/app.js`, etc que me muestre esta url:

```
midominio.com/screens/mantenimiento.html
```

deseo que no me redireccione si no mas bien me muestre el contenido de esa web pero si no ahy de otra que me redireccione.

este es mi codigo:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://midominio.com/cliente/error/migrado.html$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://midominio.com/cliente/error/migrado.html$

rewriterule ^(.*)$
https://midominio.com/screens/mantenimiento.html
[R=301,L]
```

pero no me funciona, me muestra que la pagina no existe. de antemano gracias por su ayuda

Comment: ¿Que error te aparece? ¿Así como muestras tu código, así lo tienes escrito?

Comment: que usas como handler??? apache, FastCGI o nginx??? la configuracion varia dependiendo de tu motor XD

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent apache

Comment: @alejandro00 sii tal cual esta mi codigo

Comment: apache tiene distintos motores de ejecucion, incluso algunos de esto se configuran mediante user.ini y no usan httaccess por eso te pregunto...

Answer (score 1):

Como mencionas que tal cuál como muestras tu código así es como lo tienes en tu máquina entonces el error está aquí

```text
rewriterule ^(.*)$
https://midominio.com/screens/mantenimiento.html
[R=301,L]
```

Las instrucciones en `.httaccess` son sensibles a mayúsculas.

Solo modifica eso de esta manera.

```text
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://midominio.com/screens/mantenimiento.html [R=301,L]
```